# Do I need to Close Connection when i use using?

Tags: c#, linq, sqlconnection

I have the following code:

```
newCustomerDataSourceDataContext db = GetDataContext();
{
    var tId = from t in db._CRM_Ticket_Headers
              from p in db.CRM_Priority_LKPs
              where t.created >= fromDate &&
                  t.created < toDate &&
                  t.priorityId == p.priorityId &&
                  t.statusId == status &&
                  t.employeeUserId == csrId
              select t;
}
```

Do I have to close the Connection manually, if I add `using`, and I am using **Linq** as the following:

```
using (newCustomerDataSourceDataContext db = GetDataContext())
{
    var tId = from t in db.CRM_Ticket_Headers
              from p in db.CRM_Priority_LKPs
              where t.created >= fromDate &&
                  t.created < toDate &&
                  t.priorityId == p.priorityId &&
                  t.statusId == status &&
                  t.employeeUserId == csrId
              select t;
}
```

Comment: You need not to do that. Do you facing any exception in this code ?

Comment: @RajeevKumar i am going to ensure i am closing  all connections that opened before in my website?

Comment: Its no need to do that, b'coz when you instantiate context using :
                                          
using (newCustomerDataSourceDataContext db = GetDataContext())
{ } // your db connection get closed here automatically.

Comment: website? Is this code from a controller? I think you will have to add more information about how you are using the context. There is no one-solution-fits-all here.

Comment: @AnupamSingh .what if i am using statements like ..                 newCustomerDataSourceDataContext db = new newCustomerDataSourceDataContext (); alternative newCustomerDataSourceDataContext db = GetDataContext()

Comment: then you have to use :newCustomerDataSourceDataContext.Database.Connection.Close(); when you done all insert,update or delete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you want to happen. If you use the `using` block, the `Dispose` method will be called on the context which will close the connection. However, if your application is using lazy loading, that will no longer work.

Comment: Well it's probably enabled, but only you can tell if you are using it in your code.

Answer (score 1):

No, it will be closed once you are out of using block. Resources are cleaned up when you leave that block.

Should you dispose datacontect?

> The short answer; no, you don't have to, but you should...
>
> DataContext holds state (for example, a SqlConnection and pointers to the objects you have retrieved). These will eventually get cleaned up by the GC once you release all references, but some of these objects (for example, the underlying SqlConnection) may be holding resources that you typically want to release as soon as your are finished, rather than relying on the GC to clean up.

And as was mentioned it won't work nicely if you retrieve data in lazy mode

Comment: ..do i have to use using blocks or not ??